# Registering dll

Tags: c#, windows, dll, registry

I have created a dll that requires a few things. However when I try to register it via regsvr32 it gives me the error "xxxx.dll was loaded but the entry point dllregisterserver was not found. Make sure that xxxx.dll is a valid dll or ocx file and try again."

The plugin/dll requires "System.Runtime.InteropServices" in my using clause.
It also requires that "Make assembly COM-Visible" be checked.
It also requires that I check "Register for COM interop"

If I create an installer it registers it fine and it works with out a problem.

But if I try to register it through cms with regsvr32 it fails. I have also tried with GAC util but no luck.

Has anyone came across this problem before?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Regsvr32 is for unmanaged DLL's that export DllRegisterServer() and DllUnRegisterServer().  Managed assemblies don't do this. Instead they are "COM Visible" not "COM".   You register them using Regasm and mscoree.dll is their host.  If your using a tool such as InstallShield to create an installer it'll harvest the registry entries at build time without a need to call Regasm during the install.

Comment: So to accomplish being able to register the dll with out the need of an installer, i have to add mscoree.dll to my references in my project and use regasm?

Comment: What all goes on behind the scenes when the InstallShield runs? So you helped me find out about this Regasm which definitely works I just tested it out but it must do something else, cause the .dll is still not working if I just register it via regasm.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you have custom registration code?  If you read the MSDN help topic on Regasm you'll see a note in there about regasm /regfile  not executing user code.  Basically you have to use a registry diff tool to sniff it out.

Comment: 1) Install MSI on clean VM 2) capture registry 3) run regasm  4) capture registry again 5) compare 6) manually author registry entries into installshield project 7) rinse and repeat  testing on clean VM.